# Unfortunately app has stopped in Android Emulator - Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I'm seem to be having a bit of problem with checking out my Android app on the emulator on Eclipse.  When the app is getting ready to run, I'm getting a message:

> Unfortunately App Name has stopped.

Here is the code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <Textview
                        android:id="@+id/textview1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:text="Welcome to Ambius" >
                     </Textview>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: That is not the code, post your onCreate() method here as well as the logcat stacktrace.

Comment: It looks like this question was left hanging with requests for more code. It can therefore be closed as lacking a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In order to make tabs work you also need some code in java files.

Check out these examples:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107693/Tabbed-Applications-in-Android
- http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

To enable LogCat go Window > Show View > LogCat (if its not visible, press Other... its grouped under Android)